# Где хранить данные клиента?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, cookie

Я работаю с .net mvc core, и хоче реализовать данные о просмотренности форума, т.е например если пользователь не видел ту или иную тему, она светиться, после того, как пользователь её просмотрел где-то меняется статус. Где и как можно хранить и обрабатыватт данные о статусе просмотра? Я могу бы хранить это в cookie, но ведь там ограничения по количеству данных.

Comment: Вариантов особо немного. На клиенте (в куки, в локалсторадж), на сервере.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от требований к хранению данной информации.

1. Хранить данные на время работы в браузере (в пределах браузера и сессии, имею ввиду до чистки кэша и куков). Тут можно использовать локальное хранилище браузера. [tprogger.localstorage](https://tproger.ru/articles/localstorage/)
2. Хранить данные постоянно. Т.е. пользователь может авторизоваться через другой браузер. Тут реализовать на уровне БД, добавляя связь многое-ко-многим для Пользователь - Тема форума.